# Java library to access Windows (D)COM interfaces

Tags: java

I am looking for a Java library that would allow me to access and interact with Windows COM/DCOM interfaces/objects.

I have found www.j-interop.org. I am looking if there are any alternatives to this as well.

Currently, I want this to access Windows Scheduled Tasks but later I might want to use it for other things as well, like WMI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [com4j](http://com4j.kohsuke.org/) in a project for interacting with a COM interface. You can generate a Java model with the com4j tlbimp utility and you are then interacting via Java interfaces with the COM objects which is very convenient.